# In Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Edit and Continue does not work for me

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with Edit & Continue feature after upgrading VS2015 to Upgrade 3. My current version is MS VS Community 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01, Update 3

I understand that within debugging only some changes can be applied. It was my experience until I installed VS2015 update 3. Thereafter any changes are always rejected, i.e. Edit&Continue is useless. I believe that setting in my projects is correct, (or at least it used to be for the previous versions  of VS).

I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create default Console application. Build it in default Win32 Debug configuration.
2. Set break point e.g. at line 22 that reads `HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);`
3. Start debugger. It stops at line 22.
4. Modify line 24 from `if (hModule != nullptr)` to `if (hModule != NULL)`
5. Press Apply changes on the Debug toolbar, (or press execute, step execute next line or whatever that forces VS Debugger to implement changes and continue debugging
6. The change is not accepted producing the error, see the enclosed picture.
   [image]

In fact, any change in any native Win32 Debug C++ application cannot be applied in MS VS debug session.

Libor Jendele

Comment: Could you attach the picture or error? It seems to be missing from your question.

Comment: Ok, I just checked your internal feedback item @MSFT as well. My *guess* is that you have /d2Zi+ (or some other compiler option) that is overriding /ZI (Edit and Continue) - could you check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning `ignoring unknown option '-Z+'` during recompilation indicates that the original CPP file was compiled with the undocumented compiler switch /d2Zi+ (which seems to be replaced with /Zo as per [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/838d6a5c-abea-4143-854c-5d98ff724857/d2zi-vs-zo?forum=visualstudiogeneral)). This switch is basically used to get richer debug information with optimized code ([here's a good post about it by Bruce Dawson](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/debugging-optimized-codenew-in-visual-studio-2012/)*). This messed with /ZI (Program Database with Edit and Continue) under the covers somewhat inconsistently - if the CPP file was not compiled with /ZI, the debugger/compiler should refuse to recompile it during Edit and Continue yet this slips through the cracks, causing such random/undiagnosable errors during recompilation.

The correct fix is to replace /d2Zi+ by /Zo (which is the documented and supported version of the switch), or alternatively, remove /d2Zi+ entirely from your cl command line since AFAIK it adds no value for "Debug" configurations, and Edit and Continue should work as usual.

*Note: Bruce's blog mentions that rich debugging info with the Release configuration is not available if EnC is enabled under Debug > Options, but this is outdated and currently incorrect - it's actually the option "Enable Native compatibility mode" in VS 2015 that's incompatible with /d2Zi+ (prevents optimized debugging from being rich and detailed).

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2012 Update 3 there was a [breaking changes in Edit & Continue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/01/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015-update-3/). Quote:

> Allow Precompiling (Native only): The debug option Debug > Options > General > Allow Precompiling (Native only) is no longer supported with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and the default debugger.

Disable this option, rebuild solution and try again. It should work.

Comment: @user1969843 , Nikita's suggestion is helpful, it really has some requirements/updates for the Edit & Continue feature for VC++ in VS2015 update 3: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/01/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015-update-3/

Comment: @JackZhai nice to hear, please vote up, to show that its useful

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked that all required settings are correct, (incl. disabling Allow Precompiling). I did rebuild; the problem persists!  
I thing the trouble is because of "New global or static variable 'SG228034' was added" msg, see the enclosed png with error. In every project, where I Edit and Continue, the "Apply Changes" generates in Error list similar error msg! I'm not aware of such variable in my solution; I do not change it. This must be generated internally. Please find the link to my solution https://app.box.com/s/d2d3bslq5gi1xijsvc3eem1241a9cb31
 Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1969843 Described use case works fine for me on your solution. My VS2015 version is `14.0.25425.01 Update 3`. Probably Edit & Continue broken in your `14.0.25431.01` build. On your build, for some reason compiler always generates static internal variable, but such change is [not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dbey757.aspx) by EnC and it stops.

Comment: @user1969843 Your posted solution works fine.
From your screenshot, /ZI is being overridden (most likely by /d2Zi+ which is an undocumented compiler switch).
Can you try:
1. Set Debug > Console App Properties > C/C++ > General > Suppress Startup Banner = "No"
2. Right click on your CPP file node in the Solution Explorer and click "Compile".
What's the command line that displays in the output window? That should help in figuring out what switch is overriding /ZI.

Comment: Many thanks. /d2Zi+ is there! It has been specified not in the project itself, (where I checked it 100x), but inherited from AtenaMicrosoftCpp.Win32Debug.user PropertyPage->C/C++.CommandLine->AdditionalOptions. It's probably a legacy PropertyPage that has been generated automatically when moving from a previous version of VS.

Comment: Once I removed it, all works as expected. As said, I'm grateful for the support.

Comment: @Ramkumar Thank you again. If you submit your comment as an answer, I will mark as a correct one and vote it up.